# Zurb foundation 5 - topbar search

Tags: zurb-foundation, navigationbar

have you occured that problem with zurb foundation's topbar? [image: that]  The input box doesnt fit the navigation. I didnt modify anything, just pasting the code from [foundation's page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) to their example website included into foundation files. Changing the font to Open Sans doesnt help too.

Comment: You'll have to show some code if you want help with this. As far as I can see, you're clearly missing something, if you truly did just copy and paste then the placement of the search box would be different.

Comment: sorry, the code is [here](http://pastebin.com/2si3ebwp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters, Foundation's styling for the `.top-bar input` is being overridden by the styling for the more specific `input[type="text"]`. However, even if you added the `type` attribute, the styling in the 5.0.2 release is slightly different from that of the example.

To mimic the example's styling, add the following to your own custom stylesheet, which should be added after foundation.css:

```
.top-bar input[type="text"], .top-bar .button {
    font-size: 0.77778rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}

.top-bar input[type="text"] {
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0.35rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.35rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

**Edit:** Added JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vRNt/2/

Comment: thank you, its helps more or less with the input. but i occured next problem, when i zoom in browser's window the navigation completely breaks like [that](http://imgur.com/bEXBhVw)

Comment: You can see it working in the JSFiddle I added above. Check your code against that.