# Top bar navigation form not aligned in Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I was reading the tutorial described here http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html for creating a horizontal form in the top nav bar.

I downloaded the foundation zip and added in the index.html the following:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
<ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">Top Bar Title </a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
        <li class="has-form">
                <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="small-8 columns">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns">
                        <a href="#" class="alert button">Search</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section></nav>
```

What I am getting is this:

[image: bar with search, textbox and button misaligned]

while I am expection this:

[image: bar with search, textbox and button aligned]

Any idea why the input text and the search button are not aligned?

Comment: See my answer to this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173199/zurb-foundation-5-topbar-search/20196533#20196533

Comment: Thanks a lot... I searched a lot before asking but I didn't find that thread.